# Flutter Windows : textfield does not allow space

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

I don't know if this is a bug in flutter or not but a week ago i upgraded to flutter 2.0.2
and discovered that TextField does not allow space?

> flutter doctor -v
> [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316], locale en-US)
> • Flutter version 2.0.2 at C:\Flutter\flutter-latest
> • Framework revision 8962f6dc68 (4 days ago), 2021-03-11 13:22:20 -0800
> • Engine revision 5d8bf811b3
> • Dart version 2.12.1

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
• Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
• Platform android-30, build-tools 29.0.3
• Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.9.0)
• Visual Studio at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community
• Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.9.31025.194
• Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.19041.0

[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
• Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
• Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
• Dart plugin version 191.8593
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2)
• IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2.1
• Flutter plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
• Dart plugin can be installed from:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] VS Code (version 1.54.3)
• VS Code at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
• Flutter extension version 3.20.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
• Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1316]
• Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.82
• Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 89.0.774.54

• No issues found!

Comment: Besides the issue and Flutter doctor report, You should share some piece of code from where the error is thrown.

Comment: include your code with your question. What are you doing with `TextField` how could we know if you do not show any code snippet

Comment: Sorry ,  but I discovered right now that this issue is exposed only when I put the TextField inside a AlertDialog